# 5th ed duplicate proficiencies

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, proficiency

Example, assassin rogue with the charlatan background, both the class and background specify the disguise kit as a proficiency. What do you do about that to even it out? With the second proficiency do you turn it into expertise? Or do you choose another kit to become proficient in? Or do you just lose out on a proficiency?